# Is Joomla only a matter of changing module positions or more?

Tags: joomla2.5

I'm basically a **Core PHP Programmer** and recently I've been given the task to get a grasp on **Joomla**.However I'm confused with the inner workings of Joomla.One of my project leader told me that if you master that **module positioning stuff** then that's it ...Hoping for ur quick replies..

Answer (score 4):

Joomla is `not` only about `module` positioning, it is more than that so as par as learning is concerned following few tips for you-

1. Learn `MVC` architectural design pattern.
2. Search for Modules, components and plugins, how they work and the differences.
3. How to use JOOMLA [framework](http://docs.joomla.org/Framework).
4. how to query database in JOOMLA.
5. Look for the version differences(1.5,1.6,1.7,2.5).
6. Security concerns in an application.

Good place to start - [Joomla Docs](http://docs.joomla.org/)

Have a look at the JOOMLA architecture -

[image: joomla architecture]

Source - [Image Source Link](http://docs.joomla.org/File:JoomlaArchitecture0.png)

Comment: Thnx for ur quick reply..But ur answer doesn't answer the question dat i hv posted..Nevertheless thnx 4 a guidance

Comment: @AWESOME your question is `Is Joomla only a matter of changing module positions or more?` and i believe I already added an answer in the very first line